# Getting the touched element with hammer.js and kinetic.js

Tags: jquery, kineticjs, hammer.js

Is there any possibility to get the current object?

```
for(var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
        x: Math.random() * stage.getWidth(),
        y: Math.random() * stage.getHeight(),
        radius: Math.random() * 50 + 25,
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 3,
        draggable: true,
        id: 'img'+n
    });

    var transformer = Hammer(circle);  //kineticjs stage
    transformer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
        alert(e);  // get the current object
    });

    layer.add(circle);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HF3dL/4/

e is not the current element, but the touch event. And if I try 
e.target - the element is not defined
and
e.gesture.target is the canvas element...

But I want to get the touched element..

Answer (score 0):

You may use javascript closure:

```
for(var n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
  (function(){
    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle(conf);

    var transformer = Hammer(circle);  //kineticjs stage
    transformer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
      alert(e);  // get the current object
    });

    layer.add(circle);
  })();
}
```

Or wait wait for a new version, then you will be able to use `targetNode` property:

```
 transformer.on('doubletap', function (e) {
      console.log(e.targetNode);
 });
```